# cocos2d 2.0 custom drawing causes incomplete scene rendering

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a weird problem that I have not found a solution for despite lots and lots of googling and reading.

I have a scene that uses a dynamically generated background.  The code for the background is based on this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3913/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-2) and other code I have found related to that such as Haqus Tiny-Wings github.

Anyway, my code has simplified the hill generation and it is all contained in one CCNode class called StripedTerrain.  It all works fine (now!) but when going to another scene that uses the same layout with the same background sprite, it doesnt render completely.  See the [screenshot](http://www.webpit.com/wp-content/uploads/cocos2dsceneproblem.png).  Image A is the first run with my code as is.  Image B is after a replaceScene call to a new scene of the same scene class.  Then, I made this small change to my draw code just before popping the matrix:

```
ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 255, 255);
ccDrawLine(ccp(0.0,0.0),ccp(0.0,0.0));
```

and then it works fine (images C and D)

This is the strangest thing and I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

I'll post the draw call code, but spare you the rest of the details :

```
 /**
 * Previus to the draw method we have already done the following:
 * Randomly selected, or have been given two colors to paint the stripes onto our texture
 * Generated a texture to overlay on to our hill vertice geometry
 * Generated the top of the hill peaks and valleys
 * Generated the hill verticies that will fill in the surface of the hills
 * with the texture applied
 */
- (void) draw {

CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
// this statement fixed the screwed up jagged line rendering
// since we are only using position and texcoord vertexes, we have to use this shader
kmGLPushMatrix();
CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
ccGLBlendFunc( CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST ); //TB 25-08-12: Allows change of blend function
ccGLBindTexture2D(self.stripes.texture.name);

//TB 25-08-12: Assign the vertices array to the 'position' attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices);

//TB 25-08-12: Assign the texCoords array to the 'TexCoords' attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);
//TB 25-08-12: Draw the above arrays
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices);
CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

//Debug Drawing (remove comments to enable)
if(0) {
    for(int i = MAX(_fromKeyPointI, 1); i <= _toKeyPointI; ++i) {
     ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
     ccDrawLine(_hillKeyPoints[i-1], _hillKeyPoints[i]);
     }
    for(int i =0;i<_nHillVertices;i+=3) {
        ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
        ccDrawLine(_hillVertices[i+1], _hillVertices[i+2]);
    }
}
// have to do this to force it to work the next scene load
ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 255, 255);
ccDrawLine(ccp(0.0,0.0),ccp(0.0,0.0));
kmGLPopMatrix();
CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWS(1);


}
```

Any obvious mistakes above?

I've set the shader in another method.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the previous scene and its children run their dealloc method. If not, and one or more are leaking the weirdest things can happen.

The same goes for overriding cleanup without calling super cleanup.

Comment: No, I did all the obvious things such as that.

Comment: I would inline all of ccDrawLine and see how much you can comment out before it breaks again.  Maybe something to do with ccGLEnableVertexAttribs?  That will enable kCCVertexAttrib_Color if the flag is set.